# Merging feature classes in memory gives ERROR 001156?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, merge, in-memory, error-001156

```
arcpy.AddField_management("in_memory/originalfc","ALPHABET","TEXT",1)
arcpy.Select_analysis("in_memory/originalfc","in_memory/A","attr<=0")
arcpy.CalculateField_management("in_memory/A","ALPHABET",'"A"',"PYTHON")
arcpy.Select_analysis("in_memory/originalfc","in_memory/B","attr>0")
arcpy.CalculateField_management("in_memory/B","ALPHABET",'"B"',"PYTHON")
arcpy.Merge_management(["in_memory/A","in_memory/B"],"in_memory/merged")
```

When the merge executes I get an error 001156 on OID 1 that says i can't write value 'A' to output field ALPHA.

If I try to append one to the other I get the same error. They were originally the same feature class why won't they go back together?

Comment: To which line does the error refer? The CalculateField or the Merge?

Comment: To the merge line

Comment: If you used an expression in CalculateField you could avoid needing to split and re-merge.  Something like `arcpy.CalculateField_management("in_memory/originalfc","ALPHA",'"A" if !attr! <= 0 else "B"',"PYTHON")`

Comment: Does it work when performed in a regular workspace like a file geodatabase?

Comment: @Polygeo I have the same type of issue. When I am working with a regular file geodatabase merging works fine, when I am working with in memory workspace I get the same error as above..

Comment: @GeoF  If neither of the answers below answers your question, and unless you think your question is exactly the same as this one, I think you should ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this error again and the reason it is coming up for me has to do with domains and in_memory feature classes and combining datasets in arcpy.

Example:

FeatureClass1 has attribute [NAME] with a coded value of "MR" and the domain shows "Mister"
(that fc was a selection from a larger dataset and the domain assigned in the gdb carried over to the in_memory)

FeatureClass2 has attribute [NAME] with a value of "MR" no domain attached

If I merge the two I get error 001156. 
If I append FeatureClass1 to FeatureClass2 I get error 001156.

But if I append FeatureClass2 to FeatureClass1 it works!

Answer (score 1):

IN_MEMORY is a sort of simplified "geodatabase" but obviously in memory not on a disk. Now the important thing to appreciate is that it is like a geodatabase and thus honours the many specification, but not all, of a geodatabase.

I believe you have been unlucky enough to have chosen a geodatabase RESERVED field name, ALPHA. Suggest you call it something else like "myALPHA".